# Possible to use Firebase without GCP?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

Let's say theoretically I owe GCP a lot of money and they shut down my GCP project, I've migrated to AWS so no issue there. The only thing is that I want to continue using Firebase for Authentication. Will I be able to use Firebase and pay the bill separately from my GCP account? Will google come for me?

Comment: Theoretically, I would contact Google Cloud Billing support, explain the situation, and work out a repayment plan. Yes, you need a Google Cloud project. The services that Firebase provides are hosted/provided-by Google Cloud.

Comment: @JohnHanley repayment is not an option lol. Guess ill use amplify

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, a firebase project is part of a GCP project so you won't be able to do that.
Here's a medium article on the topic.

https://medium.com/google-developers/whats-the-relationship-between-firebase-and-google-cloud-57e268a7ff6f